# set navigation bar color based on screen compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-navigation-bar

I am trying to make the device navigation bar pick up the color of the compose navigation bar without success on some devices.

The app has a compose `NavigationBar` which is not visible on all screens.
I would like the device navigation bar to pick up the color of the compose navigation bar when the latter is present and the surface color when not.

This is my code within the `Theme.kt` class.

```
@Composable
fun MyAppTheme(
darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
val colorScheme = when {
    darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
    else -> LightColorScheme
}

val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
DisposableEffect(systemUiController, darkTheme) {
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        darkIcons = !darkTheme
    )
    onDispose { }
}

MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = colorScheme,
    typography = Typography,
    content = content
)
}
```

It is working fine on android studio emulator Pixel 4,5 and 6. It is not working on physical device (Galaxy S20).

I was wondering whether it is a good idea to do something like:

```
if(showBottomAppBar){
   SideEffect {
    sysUiController.setNavigationBarColor(
        color = colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(3.dp)
    )
   }
}else{
 SideEffect {
    sysUiController.setNavigationBarColor(
        color = Color.Transparent
    )
   }
}
```